A PDE exercise using maximum principle
let $ L > 0 $ be a constant, the set
$$
\Omega := \left( -\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \times (0, L),
$$
and $ v \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega}) $ satisfy
$$
\begin{cases} 
-\Delta v + av \leq 0 & \text{in } \Omega \\
v|_{\partial \Omega} = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where the smooth function $ a $ is given and satisfies $ a(x) > -1 $ for all $ x \in \Omega $. Prove or disprove
$$
\max_{\overline{\Omega}} v \leq 0.
$$
I get trouble solving this problem. For $a(x)>0$, it is not hard to prove it. We just assume that the maximum of $v$ is attained by a point in the interior of $\Omega$, and then use the inequality to lead a contradiction. However, for $a(x)$ attains negative value, the above argument is not valid. I try to construct a counterexample by separate method. i.e. set $v(x,y)=\cos(3x/2)\cos(\pi/2+\pi y/L)$ which satisfies the bounded condition. But in this case, we need a function $a$, $a(x)<-9/4-\pi^2/L^2$,so it fails. Can anyone give any hints? Thank you so much!

Hint: There is a maximum principle involving the first Dirichlet eigenvalue.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open bounded set, $u \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline \Omega)$, and $a\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. Suppose that $u$ satisfies $$\left \{ 
\begin{array}{rl}
 -\Delta u +au \leq 0, &\text{in } \Omega \\
u\leq0,&\text{on }\partial \Omega 
\end{array}
\right . $$ and $ a\geq \mu$ for some constant $\mu$ satisfying $\mu>-\lambda_1(\Omega)$ where $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ is the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $-\Delta$. Then $u\leq 0$ in $\overline \Omega$.

Furthermore, the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of the rectangle $(0,\ell_1) \times (0,\ell_2)$ is $$ \pi^2 \bigg ( \frac 1 {\ell_1^2}+\frac 1 {\ell_2^2} \bigg ), $$ see here. Since your rectangle is (after translating) the same as $(0,\frac{2\pi}3)\times (0,L)$ the first eigenvalue of your domain is $$\pi^2 \bigg ( \frac 9 {4\pi^2}+\frac 1 {L^2} \bigg ) >\frac 9 4 >1 $$

For a proof of the maximum principle I stated above, a standard reference (from what I can tell) is Maximum principles in differential equations by Protter and Weinberger. I can’t confirm this because I don’t have access to this book, so I’ll sketch the proof below:
Consider $v=u^+:=\max \{ u(x),0\}$. If you multiply the PDE by $v$ then integrate by parts, you obtain \begin{align*}
0&\geq-\int_\Omega v \Delta u \, dx + \int_\Omega a uv \, dx\\
&= \int_\Omega \vert \nabla v \vert^2 + av^2 \, dx. 
\end{align*} Here I’ve used that $$ \nabla v = \begin{cases}
\nabla u , &\text{in } \{u>0\} \\ 0, &\text{in } \Omega \setminus \{ u>0\} 
\end{cases} , $$ so \begin{align*} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v &=  \begin{cases}
\vert \nabla u \vert^2 , &\text{in } \{u>0\} \\ 0, &\text{in } \Omega \setminus \{ u>0\} 
\end{cases}  \\ 
&= \vert \nabla v \vert^2 .
\end{align*} Since $u\leq 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, $v=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, we have $$\int_\Omega \vert \nabla v \vert^2 \, dx \geq \lambda_1(\Omega) \int_\Omega v^2 \, dx. $$ Hence, \begin{align*}
0\geq \int_\Omega \vert \nabla v \vert^2 + av^2 \, dx \geq (\lambda_1(\Omega)+\mu) \int_\Omega v^2 \, dx\geq 0.
\end{align*} Since $\mu>-\lambda_1(\Omega)$, this is only possible if $v\equiv 0$, or equivalently, $u \leq 0$ in $\Omega$.

If you want more information on the maximum principle involving the first eigenvalue (or anything else) let me know

Can I have a ref of the theorem you state here?

@AaronCheung I’ve updated my answer with a reference and a proof of the theorem
